# Is it possible to connect Selenium-IDE to ChromeDriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I;m just starting to test my app with Selenium and I have downloaded Selenium-IDE and wrote a few test cases. They run nice in Firefox and all pass. I also need to test my app in Chrome and IE. Is it possible to connect the IDE to the Chrome web driver so I can run them there as well?

Answer (score 2):

You can export the scripts as Wedbriver scripts and run it against other browser.

Comment: I saw that it only exports to programming languages (java, c#, etc). Is there any possibility to run the tests from HTML code generated by the IDE?

Answer (score 0):

Now you can,
from [How to run tests from Selenium IDE in Chrome](http://screenster.io/running-tests-from-selenium-ide-in-chrome/) :

> Ever wondered if you could use Selenium IDE for Chrome? You’ve probably heard that the IDE only runs in Firefox, which means Google’s much-famed browser is out of reach. Actually, there’s a neat little feature that lets you run Selenium IDE in Chrome.
>
> The feature is called WebDriver Playback. Here’s how you can use it:
>
> - Launch Selenium IDE.
> - Go to ‘Options’ and select “Options…” in the drop-down menu.
> - In the Options menu, select the “WebDriver” tab.
> - Check the “Enable WebDriver playback” checkbox.
> - Find the “Browser choices” input field right below the checkbox. Below the input field, you will see browser options. These include “android, chrome, firefox, htmlunit, internet explorer, iPhone, iPad”.
> - Substitute “firefox” with “chrome”. Note that both variants are lowercase.
> - Download the Selenium standalone JAR file and ChromeDriver. Add both files to the same folder on your local computer.
> - Use Terminal to navigate to the folder with the downloaded files.
> - Start Selenium server and ChromeDriver server via Terminal: java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.43.1.jar -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=chromedriver.exe
> - Open Selenium IDE and run the test script. Note that the script will run in one of the more or less recent versions of Chrome.